# Why does Google 2FA (libpam) not work in opensuse

Tags: openssh, opensuse, google-authenticator

I have a little problem with google_authenticator_libpam in openSUSE. I have tryied to find the Problem myselfe, but nothing worked. I have tested it on two systems. I installed the package google_authenticator_libpam. After that i editet the file:"/etc/pam.d/sshd"

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        required    pam_google_authenticator.so noskewadj echo_verification_code nullok
auth        requisite   pam_nologin.so
#auth        include     common-auth
account     requisite   pam_nologin.so
account     include     common-account
password    include     common-password
session     required    pam_loginuid.so
session     include     common-session
session     optional    pam_lastlog.so   silent noupdate showfailed
session     optional    pam_keyinit.so   force revoke
```

~
And I editet the file: "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" (Added)

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive,password
```

And finally i restarted the sshd service.

After those steps the SSH-Promt asks for the Verification key. When I enter the correct key, the log file: "/var/log/message" said "Invalid verification code"

My time is correct too.

Can anyone help me?
~